# How do you return a dereferenced array?

Tags: java, arrays, return

I wish to do the something like the following:

```
public static int[] plusOneLengthFour(int[] arr) {
  return {arr[0]+1,arr[1]+1,arr[2]+1,arr[3]+1};
}
```

But at compile time, I get the following error:

```
TestClass.java:5: error: illegal start of expression
        return {arr[0]+1,arr[1]+1,arr[2]+1,arr[3]+1};
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Do you want to return your array with its element incremented by 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add `new int[]` to your return statement to compile it.  It doesn't know what you want if you just start with curly braces.  Note that this will return a **new** array, while the original `arr` will have the same values.

i.e.,

```
return new int[] {arr[0]+1,arr[1]+1,arr[2]+1,arr[3]+1};
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! Thank you so much for your early and simple response!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to modify the input array, you don't need to return anything:

```
public static void plusOneLengthFour(int[] arr) {
    arr[0]++;
    arr[1]++;
    arr[2]++;
    arr[3]++;
}
```

If you want to make a new array, containing the first 4 elements of the input array incremented by 1, then the code to use is

```
public static int[] plusOneLengthFour(int[] arr) {
    return new int[] {arr[0] + 1, arr[1] + 1, arr[2] + 1, arr[3] + 1};
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! I made Jeff's answer correct because he was the first one!

Answer (score 1):

You should use below statement to return the array.

```
  return new int[] {arr[0] + 1, arr[1] + 1, arr[2] + 1, arr[3] + 1};
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! I made Jeff's answer correct because he was the first one!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to return your array, with the array elements incremented by 1. Here's how you can do it: -

```
public static void plusOneLengthFour(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
    }

}
```

In fact you don't need to return the Array. The change will be reflected in the original array.

Comment: That was just an example program that I though of on the spot. What I was trying to do was return an array without creating a reference for it ahead of time. Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your method more flexible

```
public static int[] addNumberToItems(int[] array, int valueToAdd) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] += valueToAdd;

    return array;
}
```

this constant returns array's length:

```
array.length
```

Comment: That was just an example program that I though of on the spot. What I was trying to do was return an array without creating a reference for it ahead of time. Thanks for answering though!